# ul table with li table-cell

Tags: html, css

I want to show content on two columns (and two rows in my code) using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

and CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

but I can't find any answer why does not work. Where am I wrong?

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/3Lwozhb9/

I need same height, with `display: inline-block` is no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not *quite* clear what order these `li` cells should be in but one option is use flexbox **instead** of `display:table`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1.</li>
  <li>2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque similique optio modi harum quas quae, libero provident dignissimos laboriosam et, inventore voluptatibus veritatis quos? Magnam.</li>
  <li>3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod, velit expedita? Rem eos nulla impedit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A veniam, quidem. Nisi alias deserunt facilis unde repellendus praesentium esse in consequuntur,
    dolores natus reprehenderit incidunt culpa, repellat fugiat est quis!</li>
  <li>4.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It looks perfect. Is there any chance to align content vertically down? `vertical-align: bottom` doesn't work here. Thanks!

Comment: You mean the content should be at the bottom of the `li`..then yes, updated.

Answer (score 2):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Both of the adjacent list items are the same height based on their content

Comment: Thanks. Any solution without changing current HTML?