# use css to build a table from ul li

Tags: html, css, list, html-table

I have this piece of html code. This is a list of type UL/LI with span classes inside.
I want it to be displayed as a table with boarders and not a list with bullets.

```html
<ul class="list">
<li>
<span class="category">category1</span>
<span class="name">Item Title1</span> 
<span class="price">40 EUR</span>
<span class="url"><a href="url1">link to article</a></span>
</li> 
<li>
<span class="category">category2</span>
<span class="name">item title2</span> 
<span class="price">55 EUR</span>
<span class="url"><a href="url2">link to article</a></span>
</li> 
</ul>
```

I have tried to write this css but the result is not good.

```css
.list ul {
    width: 450px;           
    position: relative;
    
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.list ul:before, ul:after {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 0;
    width: 48%;
}

.list ul:before {
    content: 'col1';
    border-right: 0;    
}

.list ul:after {
    content: 'col2';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 48%;
    margin-left: 1px;    
}

.list li {
    text-align: right;
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.list li:nth-child(even) {
    margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
<li>
<span class="category">category1</span>
<span class="name">Item Title1</span> 
<span class="price">40 EUR</span>
<span class="url"><a href="url1">link to article</a></span>
</li> 
<li>
<span class="category">category2</span>
<span class="name">item title2</span> 
<span class="price">55 EUR</span>
<span class="url"><a href="url2">link to article</a></span>
</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13825418/2358409

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ul table with li table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159666/ul-table-with-li-table-cell)

Comment: Why don't you just make it a `<table>`?

Comment: I'm trying to use https://listjs.com/ to filter and sort lists. The sample are made with UL/LI.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this effect is to use **CSS Grid**.

Right at the very start (and this is normal whenever you want to reformat a list) it's a good idea to begin by applying the following styles to the parent `<ul>` / `<ol>`:

- `margin-left: 0`
- `padding-left: 0`
- `list-style-type: none`

This acts as a very basic reset to the way either of these types of list are normally displayed.

**Working Example:**

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 180px 180px;
  width: 360px;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  list-style-type: none;
}

.list li {
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.list li span {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 9px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.list li span.category {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
<li>
<span class="category">Category 1</span>
<span class="name">Item Title 1</span> 
<span class="price">40 EUR</span>
<span class="url"><a href="url1">Link to Article</a></span>
</li> 
<li>
<span class="category">Category 2</span>
<span class="name">Item Title 2</span> 
<span class="price">55 EUR</span>
<span class="url"><a href="url2">Link to Article</a></span>
</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not producing the result I want. If I create a third entry, it creates 1 row with 2 columns and a second row. Each LI must become a single row.

Comment: more exactly, each <li> must become 1 row, each <span category,name,price,url> must become 1 column.

Comment: But now you know the right tools (one of them, at any rate - the other one is _CSS Tables_) you can learn and experiment and achieve the result you want.

Comment: If you want to learn _CSS Grid_, I strongly recommend both: [CSS Grid Garden](https://cssgridgarden.com/) and [A Complete Guide to Grid by CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 1):

```html
  
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td class="category">category1</td>
    <td class="name">Item Title1</td>
    <td class="price">40 EUR</td>
    <td class="url"><a href="url1">link to article</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="category">category2</td>
    <td class="name">item title2</td>
    <td class="price">55 EUR</td>
    <td class="url"><a href="url2">link to article</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: could be fine If I could filter and sort it.

Comment: Use https://datatables.net/ (Jquery Datatable) for sorting and filtering and for better table display.

Answer (score 0):

You are styling a list inside an element with the list class instead of the list itself here:

```
.list ul {
    width: 450px;           
    position: relative;

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

If you add a .list element outside the list, or refactor the style to point the list itself you'll be pointed in the right direction.

This piece, for example, will work with the following modification:

```
.list {
    width: 450px;           
    position: relative;

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Or you can also alter the html:

```
<div class="list">
<ul>
<li>
<span class="category">category1</span>
<span class="name">Item Title1</span> 
<span class="price">40 EUR</span>
<span class="url"><a href="url1">link to article</a></span>
</li>   
<li>
<span class="category">category2</span>
<span class="name">item title2</span> 
<span class="price">55 EUR</span>
<span class="url"><a href="url2">link to article</a></span>
</li>   
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can' modify <ul class="list"> . I need it to filter and sort the list with  listjs.com. The sample start with class structure that I posted. I want to generate a sortable and filterable table. So i just want the piece of code I posted to be displayed as a  "standard" table with  borders and cells.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to build a correct table from this html piece.
Instead I generated a table and managed to use list.js to filter the content.
This achieved what I wanted to do.